Logout from ASP.NET Core application which has authorisation service but no authentication service
I have inherited a C# DevExpress ASP.NET Core Blazor project which runs on an IIS server.
The application has authorisation enabled and this requires the user to login with their domain credentials when they first open the page on the browser. After they login, they are authorised to different levels based on their membership of groups on the machine running the IIS server.  IIS settings enable windows authentication, the application itself does not add any authentication service.
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iis": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/MyApp",
        "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59638",
        "sslPort": 44394
    }
},

All this works fine, however, I want to add the ability for the user to log off from the browser without needing to shut the browser down, but am not sure how I go about this.
My questions are:

Can I clear the current authorisation token from the Razor web page? If so, how do I do this?

If I cannot clear authorisation, what type of authentication do I need to add?



You are using the windows auth for this blazor application?

IIS has windows authentication enabled, but there is no authentication service added to the application itself.

There is no logout from Windows authentication (since classic ASP and ASP.NET).

Thanks for the information, is there anything that can be added to my application to allow login / logout, or is that it?

If don't use windows auth and you should modify your  project, is it OK?

Hello Brando, that's what I am trying to work out. Do the other methods of Authentication also use windows accounts on the machine, if so which one? I am happy to add authentication to the application and not use iis to authenticate

I suggest you could consider using the cookie auth. More details, you could refer to this article.  And this support the aplication login out.
